# i want to align picture to the extreme right of the slider(it should be responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align the picture to the extreme right of the slider, i did try margin-left but its not working in all sizes of the screen. i want to make it responsive as well so that the picture remains on extreme left in all sizes of the screen. please help.
Below is the code of the slider.

```css
   


/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
#first-slider .slide1 {
  
    background-color: blue; 
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
      
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,300i,400,500" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body><div id="first-slider">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
       
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         
            <div class="item active slide1">
                <div class="row"><div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                        

                     
                        <a style="background-color: #272a2e; font-weight: 500; font-size: 14px; border: black; " href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg da-link">
                  IP CAMERAS </a>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                        <img style="" width="100%" height="100%" data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://grandstream.com.pk/img/cam.png">
                    </div>
                </div></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item 3 -->
          
    
        </div>
        <!-- End Wrapper for slides-->
     
    </div>
</div></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left` will create a space to the left of your element, but unless the value is variable (like 95vw), then the position will not be responsive.

You should instead use either `position` or `float` to achieve the desired effect, depending on which side you want (you stated extreme right, then extreme left).

For example:

```
<style>
.carousel {
  position: relative; }
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; } // or left
</style>
```

or

```
<style>
.slide {
  float: right; } // or left
</style>
```

I'd note that if you're using a jQuery plugin for the carousel, there is likely a stylesheet or injected styles from jQuery that affect the slide's position.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So should I apply position:relative to the picture right? or the slider??

Comment: No, `position: relative` should be applied to the element that wraps around the slide. The slide is positioned absolute.